# Advice about fixing SQL Server 2014 database performance

Tags: performance, sql-server

I noticed that a system I have in a production server is running slow so I start studying about the causes. This is a SQL Server 2014 database whose data file size is 361.472 KB and log file was 427.392 KB before I shrunk it. I shrunk only log file so that its size was decreased to 1024 KB.

Then I have checked used data file space and I saw this:

[image]

I noticed that the data file is increasing very often by 1 MB. For example, on March 11th, the file size was increased a lot of times.

Instead of shrinking the data file, I prefered to set the autogrowth setting. I set it to 48 MB.

Is this a good number? is there other consideration I can take?

thanks
Jaime

Comment: Growing the database or log is a resource intensive task. But impact on a database this small should be negligible, unless your storage is really slow. As you can see it took only milliseconds. You should never shrink the database or log unless some run away query ballooned it unexpectedly. The title mentions fixing performance? What’s the performance problem? If it’s database growth set some reasonable minimums so that it happens far and few between. Is there a reason everything is set so small?

Comment: @Appleoddity Database was slow. I noticed that by shrinking the log, database queries perform better. I am evaluating to increase memory to the machine, but before doing so, I want to know if there are some other actions I can take in the database configuration.

Comment: Do you have a daily task scheduled to defragment indexes and update statistics on that database server?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo No

Answer (score 0):

@jstuardo,

You can reserve more space on your databases to avoid autogrow events and their performace impact. Shrinking database files has also negative performance impact as explained **[here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-does-shrinking-a-sql-server-log-file-affect-performance?msclkid=ec57af07bb3a11ec832527f122914def)**.

My suggestion, first please consider creating a daily maintenance task to update statistics and defragment indexes. Please download **[Ola Hallengren scripts](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=a85e24640460f7204120accdf7455289fc69eec85aa839ccbabe3c5293637539JmltdHM9MTY0OTg1OTI1OCZpZ3VpZD0xZGFmY2YzOS1jOWJjLTQ4YmItYTBkNS0wMzk3Yjk3NjA0ZWUmaW5zaWQ9NTE0MA&ptn=3&fclid=01a72eb8-bb34-11ec-a8a1-de4c998c7068&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9vbGEuaGFsbGVuZ3Jlbi5jb20vP21zY2xraWQ9MDFhNzJlYjhiYjM0MTFlY2E4YTFkZTRjOTk4YzcwNjg&ntb=1)** and run then as shown below:

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
 @Databases = 'YourDatabase',
 @FragmentationLow = NULL,
 @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
 @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
 @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
 @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
 @Indexes = 'ALL_INDEXES'
GO
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'YourDatabase',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = NULL,
@FragmentationHigh = NULL,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
GO
```

In addition, create any missing indexes as explained **[here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/?msclkid=e77a5dd8bb3711ec817c4a26c09d0061)**.

Configure TempDB properly as explained **[here](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/07/15/configure-multiple-tempdb-database-files-while-installing-sql-server-2016-new-feature/?msclkid=ea422707bb3911ec808e38f0916f4c3b)**.

Make sure the storage subsystem has read/write latency below 20 ms

This should improve performance on your database server.